# Cointegration of I(0) and I(1)

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Is it reasonable to consider cointegration between 4 series, where 3 of them are $I(1)$, and one of them is $I(0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't consider cointegration, because *by definition* of what it means to be cointegrated, the series all have to be integrated.  In your case, all four series have to be I(1), and there must exist some linear combination of them that is I(0), in order for them to be cointegrated.

Comment: Thank you. Then how to find the long-run equilibrium parameters?

Comment: You can still do cointegration analysis on the three I(1) series.  If you find some cointegrating relationship(s), the fourth variable could be added to the error-correction model as an exogenous variable.